# difference between creating an array "normally" and with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I was messing with C pointers to pointers in functions to learn. I created a string array, and wanted to change it in the function `foo` with a pointer to pointer. I then print it, just to see.

Problem is: if I create it "normally": `char array[] = "yeah"`, the code doesn't work and I see a bunch of weird characters on the console. But, If I create it with a `malloc`, it works. I really want to understand the difference.

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(char **ptr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *array = malloc(sizeof("yeah"));  //I need to malloc here, or it doesn't work. Why ?
    strcpy(array, "yeah");

    printf("array before : %s \n", array);

    char *ptr = array;
    char **pt = &ptr;

    foo(&array);

    printf("array after : %s \n", array);

    free(array);
}

void foo(char **ptr) {
    char *truc = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);  //I need to malloc here, else it doesn't work. Why ?
    strcpy(truc, "then");

    *ptr = truc;
}
```

but this doesn't, it prints nasty characters on the console:

```
void foo(char **ptr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char array[] = "yeah"; //created "normally"

    printf("array before : %s \n", array);

    char *ptr = array;
    char **pt = &ptr;

    foo(&array);

    printf("array after : %s \n", array);

    free(array);
}

void foo(char **ptr) {
    char truc = "then";

    *ptr = truc;
}
```

What is the difference between:

```
char array[] = "yeah";
```

and

```
char *array = malloc(sizeof("yeah");
strcpy(array, "yeah");
```

Comment: There are quite a few issues with this code, it won't compile without warnings on gcc 8.2.0 for me. I'd suggest compiling with `-Wall` and try to fix the warnings first.

Comment: It works fine for me, so long as you change ```char array[] = "yeah";``` to ```char* array = "yeah";```.

Comment: An array and a pointer may have the same value, but one is a constant value and other is a variable at some memory location. The difference between `int *a; a = malloc(...)` and `int a[] = ...` is the same as the difference between `int x= 5` and `5`.

Comment: anonmess yeah, I don't understand these error, and as a noob, I don't compile with the console, only atom on code::blocks ^^'

Comment: Lee Daniel Crocker  so, do you know why I need to malloc in main so my code works ?

Comment: Your "working" code has a memory leak. Function `foo` overwrites `main`'s `array` pointer with a new value obtained from `malloc`. The old value was obtained by an earlier call to `malloc` and is now unreachable storage. `foo(&array)` says: "here is the address of my non-`const` pointer: you may overwrite it, if you like", and `foo` does exactly that, without freeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Array Way

**First thing you should note: The code: `char array[] = "yeah";` will work.**
*Note: if you do this, you do not call `free(array)` because it is not a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory, and does not need to be dynamically returned to the heap. It exists on the stack. Read on...*

But the function `foo()` here is the problem. When `foo()` is called, the string `truc` (which also could be declared `char truc[] = "then";`) exists in a stack frame, which is a section of program memory, which only exists until `foo()` returns. If you change `array` to point to memory within that stack frame, what happens when that function returns? That stack frame becomes undefined, and you're left pointing at junk memory.

If you want to change the contents of the string in `array`, you could ensure the buffer is long enough, and `foo()` could `strcpy(array, "then")` into it. So, you're not changing the pointer itself, just the memory it points to. This isn't what I'd call good software design, but for the sake of an example, it would work for you. Like this:

```
void foo(char * ptr)
{
    strcpy(ptr, "then");
}
```

---

## So why doesn't it work without `malloc()` in `main()`?

When you *don't* `malloc()` in `main()`, `array` represents, as it suggests, an array. The identifier is not itself a pointer, it is an array; however, it *decays to a pointer*, or if you will, acts like one. That's why you could pass it off as one, if you wanted, like if you passed it to `foo()`. Now, if you reference the *address of* `array`, like `&array`, `(char*)array`, `&array`, `&array[0]` are all the same - pointers to the beginning of `array`. Your `foo()` is actually writing a *memory address* to the memory of `array`, in this case.

What does this do? Well, the technical answer is undefined behavior. But I would guess that it's writing a 32-bit integer (a memory address) to a chunk of memory that used to represent 4 8-bit characters in a string. So now you've corrupted exactly four characters. And, if `foo()` is using `malloc()` as you show, also introduced a memory leak.

The neat part of this is that your string is exactly four characters, so this shouldn't corrupt the null terminator `'\0'` at the end of the string. Let me guess, you see exactly four junk characters?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't explain why the code still doesn't work when I do a malloc in foo() but not in main. Is there a difference ? I tried with only one malloc in foo and array declared "normally" in main, and it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: I was going to comment back, but there is much more helpful explanation I could offer than a comment could allow. So I edited with updates. Hope that helps!